# "I'd"" as a contraction of "I did"

Tags: contractions

Here is a part of original transcription:

> Like, a lot of people would like make jewelry and sell it.  A lot of people
>   would sell, uh, clothes that they made, um....  Another, uh, favorite amongst
>   people was to, uh, just, uh, sell beer or to make food.  And that’s what I actually did a lot of the times.  I’d make sandwiches or I’d sell beer in order to help, y’know, defray the cost of the tickets

I am wondering about the last sentence with the contraction "I'd". The person in this text is saying that it sold beer and made food but at the end we have the contraction "I'd" which indicates on would usage (then I think it sounds quite unlogical). What does "I'd" mean in this case?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It's a contraction of "I would".

Comment: "I'd" generally serves as a contraction of either "I would" or "I had." I can't think of a situation where it would sound natural as a contraction of "I did." As Hot Licks points out, the instances of "I'd" that occur in your transcription are contracted forms of "I would."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the contractions in that paragraph are for would, not did.

"That's what I did a lot of the time. I would make sandwiches or I would sell beer". That use of the helping verb would means: used to do something thing. It indicates an ongoing activity. In fact, the first sentence shows the rest of the activities are, in fact, "used to do" activities. A lot of people would sell clothes=A lot of people used to sell clothes. Same meaning.

Using would like that is an alternative way of expressing: used to [verb] as an ongoing activity that was habitual in the  past.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure I've ever seen "I'd" used as an contraction of "I did".  Generally it's either "I would" or "I had".

Comment: Of course, there is no contraction for I + did. But what is interesting is how it's a stand-in for used to. That is what a non-native might not know...